# Add target to Button in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I want to implement different targets in different cases to a button.

If its the own profile of the current user, the button should add the target "go to settings". If its a different user, I want to add a follow/unfollow action.

After checking all parameters, my code should work. But it doesn't work.
I added some prints but the button is not clickable.

```
func setupUserInformation(user: UserModel) {
    usernameLabel.text = user.username

    if user.uid == UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID {
        editButton.setTitle("Einstellungen", for: .normal)

        editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToSettings), for: .touchUpInside)

    } else {
        if user.isFollowing! == true {
            setupUnfollowButton()
        } else {
            setupFollowButton()
        }
    }
}

@objc func goToSettings() {
    delegate?.goToSettingVC()
}

func setupFollowButton() {
    editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    editButton.clipsToBounds = true

    editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 84 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    editButton.setTitle("Folgen", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(followAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func followAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == false {
        FollowApi.shared.followAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupUnfollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = true

    }
}

func setupUnfollowButton() {
    editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    editButton.clipsToBounds = true

    editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    editButton.setTitle("Entfolgen", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(unFollowAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func unFollowAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == true {
        FollowApi.shared.unfollowAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupFollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = false

    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

Made some changes as in the answers below. But still the add target will be not carried out.

```
var user: UserModel? {
    didSet {
        guard let _user = user else { return }
        setupUserInformation(user: _user)
    }
}

func setupUserInformation(user: UserModel) {

    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    if user.uid == UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID {
        editButton.setTitle("Einstellungen", for: .normal)

    }else {
        if user.isFollowing! == true {
            setupUnfollowButton()
        } else {
            setupFollowButton()
        }
    }

}

@objc func didTapEditButton() {

    //Add IF conditions according to what your button should do in different cases here.
    if user!.uid == UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID {
        editButton.setTitle("Einstellungen", for: .normal)
        goToSettings()
    }else {
        if user!.isFollowing! == true {
            unFollowAction()
        } else {
            followAction()
        }
    }

}

@objc func goToSettings() {
    delegate?.goToSettingVC()
}

func setupFollowButton() {
    editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    editButton.clipsToBounds = true

    editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 84 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    editButton.setTitle("Folgen", for: UIControl.State.normal)
}

func followAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == false {
        FollowApi.shared.followAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupUnfollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = true

    }
}

func setupUnfollowButton() {
    editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    editButton.clipsToBounds = true

    editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    editButton.setTitle("Entfolgen", for: UIControl.State.normal)
}

func unFollowAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == true {
        FollowApi.shared.unfollowAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupFollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = false

    }
}
```

Comment: What does “it doesn't work” mean?

Comment: My code don't execute the addTarget.

Comment: What does that mean? Did you set a breakpoint and step thru your code?

Comment: Yes. The "editButton.setTitle("Entfolgen", for: UIControl.State.normal)" is displaying in my app. But the code runs not through "editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(unFollowAction), for: .touchUpInside)" and the prints are not displayed

Comment: That is impossible. If the Entfolgen line is executed, the next line is executed after it.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand what `addTarget` does? Note that adding a target does not execute the action code; it just sets up the button for what it _will_ do when tapped by the user later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Matt is right!! your approach is totally wrong here. Please try to modify your approach.

Your approach should be something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set Target to your button only once.
    editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapEditButton), for: .touchUpInside)

}

@objc func didTapEditButton() {

    //Add IF conditions according to what your button should do in different cases here. 
    if user.uid == UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID {
        goToSettings()
    }else {
        if user.isFollowing! == true {
            setupUnfollowButton()
        } else {
            setupFollowButton()
        }
    }

}


func setupFollowButton() {

    //Make the check to see what state your button is currently in by checking if the title of the button is "Follow" or "Unfollow"
    if editButton.titleLabel?.text == "Unfollow"{
        editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        editButton.clipsToBounds = true

        editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 84 / 255, blue: 147 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
        editButton.setTitle("Follow", for: UIControl.State.normal)

        followAction()
    }
}


 func setupUnfollowButton() {

    //Do the same here for the other state.
    if editButton.titleLabel?.text == "Follow"{
        editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        editButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        editButton.clipsToBounds = true

        editButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        editButton.setTitle("Unfollow", for: UIControl.State.normal)

        unFollowAction()
    }
}


func followAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == false {
        FollowApi.shared.followAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupUnfollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = true

    }
}

func unFollowAction() {
    print("Button wurde gedrückt")
    if user?.isFollowing == true {
        FollowApi.shared.unfollowAction(withUser: user!.uid!)
        setupFollowButton()
        user?.isFollowing = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that adding a target does not execute the action code; it just sets up the button for what it will do when tapped by the user later.

Once you realize this, you will probably see that your whole approach here is probably a bad idea. Do not try to set the target and action conditionally. Instead just set the target and action once and for all. Then inside the action method, that is where you put conditions to decide what to do whenever the button is tapped.

Comment: Thank your for your fast answer. How can I put conditions in action methods?

Comment: With the word `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem with the following code line:

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Just forgot to deactivate the user interaction with the collection view. When I tapped the button, the collection view header has been activated and not the button.

Thanks guys for your help!